# How to display class or id function in opencart 2.0 if select option value?

Tags: php, html, opencart

```
<div class="form-group required">
    <label class="col-sm-2 control-label" for="input-name">Type</label>
    <div class="col-sm-10">
        <select name="name" id="input-name" class="form-control">
            <option value="image" selected="selected">image</option>
            <option value="text">text</option>
        </select>
    </div>
</div>
```

I am using this code . In these if i select option image display only

```
<div class="function1">Function1</div>
```

If select option text display only

```
<div class="function2">Function2</div>
```

Any one please help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Opencart 2 has jQuery included. Assuming the divs with class `function1` and `function2` are already hidden, you would have:

```
$('#input-name').change(function(){
    if($(this).val() == 'image') {
        $('.function1').show();
        $('.function2').hide();
    }
    else if($(this).val() == 'text') {
        $('.function2').show();
        $('.function1').hide();
    }
});
```